# (docker-compose + nginx load balancing) + Jenkins?

Tags: nginx, jenkins, docker, load-balancing, docker-compose

Hey my fellow brogrammers :0

Currently experimenting the nginx load balancing with docker-compose.

I've got 2 node services

```
  ping1:
    ports:
      - "80"
    build:
      context: ./node
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - front-t

  ping2:
    build:
      context: ./node
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - front-t
```

And an nginx service inside of which I've configured the load balancing, and it's perfectly working!

The question now is, how can I connect Jenkins in there, to basically take one of these node services off once there's an update, apply the changes, bring it up, and then do the same to the other node service.

I'm trying to avoid having a lot of downtime everytime there are changes.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment instead of an answer because technically it's not what you asked. This scenario is exactly what Kubernetes (K8s) is for. You'd have your CI system push a new image and pod config to the K8s master, and then it will do a rolling upgrade for you.

Comment: @FelicianoTech Your answer got me into Kubernetes. I love it, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Enjoy. :)